# Using Update CONCAT to ADD data to already Existing data in Database

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to make a program update inside the database however i have one worry.
When i issue an update statement to the mysql server, i want it to ADD another data to the MYSQL database, it just overwrites the first data there and saves the new data to the database. What i want it to do is to add another data to the database plus the already existing one there.

My code looks like this

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('inc/config.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('Location: signon.php');
}
?>

<?php
require_once('inc/config.php');

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user,$pass, $db) or die ('Cannot Connect: '.mysqli_error());
//get parameters

$inst_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['inst_name']);
$inst_name2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['inst_name2']);
$grade = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['grade']);
$study_course = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['study_course']);
$qualification = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['qualification']);
$other_qualification = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['other_qualification']);
$completion_year = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['completion_year']);


$data ="inst_name = '".$inst_name."',inst_name2 = '".$inst_name2."',grade = '".$grade."', study_course = '".$study_course."',qualification = '".$qualification."',other_qualification = '".$other_qualification."',completion_year = '".$completion_year."'";


//$sql = "UPDATE user_info SET inst_name = '".$inst_name."',inst_name2 = '".$inst_name2."',grade = '".$grade."', study_course = '".$study_course."',qualification = '".$qualification."',other_qualification = '".$other_qualification."',completion_year = '".$completion_year."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";

$sql = "UPDATE user_info SET $data=CONCAT($data,inst_name = '".$inst_name."',inst_name2 = '".$inst_name2."',grade = '".$grade."', study_course = '".$study_course."',qualification = '".$qualification."',other_qualification = '".$other_qualification."',completion_year = '".$completion_year."') WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Failed Query: '.mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_close($con);
    header("Refresh:0; url=EDWE.php");
    ?>
```

What apparently am i not doing correctly.

Comment: don't update data insert it with on duplicate key, ref documentation
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @KundanPrasad you mean something like this $sql = "insert into user_info (inst_name, inst_name2,grade,study_course,qualification,other_qualification,completion_year) values ('".$inst_name."', '".$inst_name2."','".$grade."','".$study_course."','".$qualification."','".$other_qualification."','".$completion_year."') on duplicate key update 
inst_name = values(inst_name),
inst_name2 = values(inst_name2),
grade = values(grade),
study_course = values(study_course),
qualification = values(qualification),
other_qualification = values(other_qualification),

  ";

Comment: you are too close $sql = "insert into user_info (inst_name, inst_name2,grade,study_course,qualification,other_qualificat‌​ion,completion_year) values ('".$inst_name."', '".$inst_name2."','".$grade."','".$study_course."','".$quali‌​fication."','".$othe‌​r_qualification."','‌​".$completion_year."‌​') on duplicate key update inst_name = '".$inst_name."', inst_name2 = '".inst_name2."',field=value,.........; and so no

Answer (score 0):

To create a new record, rather than updating an existing one, try an SQL `INSERT` statement rather than using `UPDATE`.  `INSERT` creates records and `UPDATE` edits existing ones.

Comment: Means what i have to do is i have to create a new table and save the records inside the Database,positive it can contain a column say for name or something to match the other table not so?

Answer (score 0):

First select the existing data from the table for that user

```
Select * from user_info WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'
```

Then concat the new data to the existing data
for example for grade

```
$grade_posted_data = $_POST['grade']);
$grade_existing data = $fetched_data['grade'];
$grade=$grade_existing_data.','.$grade_posted_data;////// using whatever separator you require
```

Then update your query

```
$sql = "UPDATE user_info SET $data=CONCAT($data,inst_name = '".$inst_name."',inst_name2 = '".$inst_name2."',grade = '".$grade."'..etc etc....) WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
```